# PropTypes React Native is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, react-proptypes

I have a problem with PropTypes in react native my code :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export default class Star extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( <Text> Hello </Text> );
    }
}

Star.propTypes = {
    fullStar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    halfStar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    emptyStar: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    half: PropTypes.bool,
    count: PropTypes.number,
    size: PropTypes.number,
}

Star.defaultProps = {
    fullStar: "",
    halfStar: "",
    emtyStar: "",
    half: 'true',
    count: 5,
    size: 30,
}
```

My error is undefined is not an object (evaluating '_react2.PropTypes.string')

Thanks for read ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`PropTypes` moved into separate package. Use `prop-types` package.

More info [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html).

> **Note:**
>
> `React.PropTypes` has moved into a different package since React
>   v15.5. Please use the [prop-types library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) instead. We provide a
>   codemod script to automate the conversion.

Comment: I do this `import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';` and then do `PropTypes.number` . I get an error **undefined is not an object.(evaluating PropTypes.number)** Please see that I use **React - v15.3.2** Do I need to make the change ? import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

Comment: @Saurabh yes you do.

Comment: But according to the comment and documents online, isnt it deprecated from React v15.5 ?? Can you give me more insights on this? Referring to [link](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/04/07/react-v15.5.0.html)

Comment: @Saurabh without seeing the code it is hard to give you a solution. Problem can be caused by something else. If the suggested answer doesn't solve your problem, feel free to open up a new question with more detail for your case.

Comment: I am facing the same issue even after using import PropTypes from 'prop-types';"  can anyone help?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, PropTypes has been deprecated from version 15.x
you need to install the package:

```
npm install prop-types
```

and then import it.

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you face this kind of issue, this will be helpful.
In lastest react native version(0.58.3), Project included 'react-native-collapsible-bar' packages had this error

```
Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'React.PropTypes.oneOf')
```

I could find that this module has below dependencies too.

```
"prop-types": "^15.5.10",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^3.3.0"
```

First, I had commented below code in BarCollapsible.js

```
   static propTypes = {
         style: View.propTypes.style,
         titleStyle: Text.propTypes.style,
         tintColor: PropTypes.string,
   }
```

And then I had uninstalled react-native-vector-icons and reinstall with latest version and finally got rid out of error.

Answer (score 0):

Some time if you install any node module that is not updated with latest react native for that you have change in every js file where proptype is imported

```
replace
import {PropTypes} from 'react';
with
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```