# Error "undefined is not an object" in React Native App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, jsx, react-proptypes

I am new working with React Native and Expo XDE, I am implementing the PropTypes in the file TaskList.js of type arrayOf but at the time of compiling the application I get an error indicating "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react3.default.PropTypes.arrayOf ') "and even if I add another PropTypes of type String or another the same thing happens.

How can I solve this problem with the PropTypes?

**Error**

[image: error]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
  "start": "react-native-scripts start",
  "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
  "android": "react-native-scripts android",
  "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
  "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0"
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ListView } from 'react-native';
import TaskList from './TaskList';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      todos:[
        {
          task : "Learn React Native"
        },
        {
          task : "Learn Redux"
        },
     ]
    }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TaskList todos={this.state.todos}/>
     </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

**TaskList.js**

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {View, Text, Button, ListView} from 'react-native';

class TaskList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context){
    super(props, context);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !==   r2});

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(props.todos),
    }

  }

  renderRow =(todo)=>{
    return(
      <Text>{todo.task}</Text>
    )
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          key={this.props.todos}
          renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
        />
      </View>
   )
  }
}

TaskList.propTypes = {
  todos: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object).isRequired,
}

export default TaskList;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PropTypes React Native is not an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46791337/proptypes-react-native-is-not-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PropTypes were moved into their separate NPM package (v15+), [`prop-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prop-types) and no longer exist on the React package. That's why it is reported as `undefined`. Install it and import:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
```

Comment: I installed the dependency "prop-types " and verified that appears in the file "package. json", but still continues with the same error

Comment: @DavidNavarroAstudillo It's `prop-types`.

Comment: Maybe another dependency is missing or reinstall all dependencies again?

Comment: @DavidNavarroAstudillo Have you changed the import too...?

Comment: Yes, i writed it as you indicated me "Import PropTypes from 'prop-types';"

Comment: @DavidNavarroAstudillo And did you remove your other import?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167564/discussion-between-david-navarro-astudillo-and-li357).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the dependency

```
npm install --save prop-types
```

This command install prop-types in your project. Check your package.json file in your project

```
 "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1"
 }
```

And import it on your project where you want to use. by importing following package

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; // ES6
```